# ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR in a button onClick event when trying to export a DataTable to CSV

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm getting an error when clicking a button on a page to export data from a DataTable to a CSV file:

```
ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

This error only occurs on the published build. Everything works fine on my local machine in the development environment. It's published to a local machine on the network and then communicates directly with that, rather than over the internet (everything is local and on site, I should say). My assumption is threading being the issue, but I'm not sure how else to display dialog to the user and allow them to specify a path **AND** filename without SaveFileDialog.

```
protected void btnExportToCSV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try
    {
        int count = 1;
        int totalColumns = dataTable.Columns.Count;
        List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();

        // add the column names/headers
        foreach (DataColumn dr in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            columnNames.Add(dr.ColumnName);

            sb.Append(dr.ColumnName);
            if (count != totalColumns)
            {
                sb.Append(",");
            }
            count++;
        }
        sb.AppendLine();
        string value = String.Empty;

        // add the values for each row in corresponding column
        foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < totalColumns; x++)
            {
                value = dr[x].ToString();

                // filter out commas, line breaks, new lines and tabs
                if (value.Contains(",") || value.Contains("\"") || value.Contains("<br />") || value.Contains("\t"))
                {
                    value = '"' + value.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + '"';
                }

                // check that if current column is serial number,
                // concat a character string to force it to display as a string
                if (columnNames[x] == "SerialNum")
                {
                    value = value.Insert(0, "#");
                }
                sb.Append(value);

                // if not at the final column of a row, go to new column and NOT a new row
                if (x != (totalColumns - 1))
                {
                    sb.Append(",");
                }
                
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblVerify.Text = "There was an issue building the CSV file data; please report the following message to xxxxxxx: " + ex.Message;
        lblVerify.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }

    Stream myStream;

    // build save dialog window with options
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog
    {
        DefaultExt = "txt",
        Title = "Save Reports",
        Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*",
        InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
        RestoreDirectory = true,
    };

    try
    {
        // separate thread to open and run save file browser
        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // make sure the filename field is not blank
                if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    myStream.Close();

                    // write the csv file to disk using the given file name
                    File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName.ToString(), sb.ToString());
                }
            }
        });

        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
    }
    catch(Exception ee)
    {
        lblVerify.Text = "There was an issue exporting the data to a CSV file; please report the following message to xxxxxxx: " + ee.Message;
        lblVerify.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to include the button, if that'll help:

```<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnExportToCSV" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" BackColor="#008000" OnClick="btnExportToCSV_Click" Text="Export to CSV" Width="255" />```